# Error in my Java code?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to complete a project where a user inputs a `String` and then my program displays that `String` **reversed**. I was able to do this but I need to do it with message and input boxes which is giving me trouble. My code has an error on **line 12**. It says:

```
Error: The method showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component, java.lang.Object) in the type javax.swing.JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (java.lang.String)
```

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class reverse
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String string;
     JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a string");
     string = input.nextLine();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString());
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here with your question, not in a link. Links can go dead, and links may hold large programs, programs too large to ask a volunteer to review. Your compliance with this request will be greatly appreciated and will likely help you in getting better and faster help.

Comment: There. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

The error explains the problem, you are passing the wrong type of parameter to showMessageDialog.
A quick google search got me this page: http://alvinalexander.com/java/joptionpane-showmessagedialog-examples-1
Which indicates you need to create a 'frame' for the message dialog and pass that as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is, use the JOptionPane as the source to get input from user, so you don't need the Scanner. Once you store the string from user then you can instantiate a StringBuilder with that.

When using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog you have to pass null as first arg that is for component.

```
String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a string");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string); 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.reverse().toString());
```

A more complete and validation proof solution would look as follow:

```
 public static void main(String... args) {
        String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a String to reverse it");
        if (string != null && string.length() > 0) {
            StringBuilder reversedString = new StringBuilder(string);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, reversedString.reverse().toString());
        } else {
            //validation in case Cancel/Close button or empty input provided
            if (string == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No input provided.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "empty input provided.");
            }
        }
    }
```

To reverse a `String` without using `StringBuilder` you can make use of a `for loop` to do so. You start looping on original string one character at a time but, you start from end and come to the beginning. Inside the loop, one character at a time you create reverse of the original string. See below:

```
String originalString= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a string");
String reversed = "";   

//loop from end of string to the beginning
for(int i = originalString.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    /*
     * Use the previous value of reversed, add to it new character
     * this addition causes a new string to be created internally since
     * String is immutable
     */
    reversed += originalString.charAt(i);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

//This should work:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class reverse 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a string");

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString());

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. But I do have one more question. I showed my teacher the updated code and she said we are not aloud to use string builder... So is there any way to do this without string builder? But even if you don't know thank you so much for this because I now know how to display text in message boxes correctly which will really help me out in long run.

Comment: @logonin you can reverse a string without use of **StringBuilder** using **for loop** instead. I have updated my answer to include the instructions on how to do it.